# Responsive Ad Label around adsense

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have my site on the whitelist for AdBlock. In order to do so, I need to encapsulate all my advertisement with a label. I was able to add the label but it's not responsive and sometimes the ad will overlap. May I ask what's a better way to create a label around adsense advertisement.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <span class="Ad-label">Advertisement</span>
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row-sm-height">
                <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                <!-- Responsive Banner Ad -->
                <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                     style="display: block"
                     data-ad-client="ca-pub-2315506723267173"
                     data-ad-slot="5172135644"
                     data-ad-format="auto">
                </ins>
                <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

.Ad-label {
    color: #444;
    background: #ddd;
    font-family: arial;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: left top;
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: left top;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    position: absolute;
    left: 13%;
    top: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
}

[1]
```

Comment: Can you put this in a fiddle so we can edit it more easily?

Comment: Hi, I tried actually but nothing appeared because it's a google adsense ad.

Comment: Please make a fake ad in fiddle.

Comment: Or give us more information.
Is this ad displayed vertically on the left or right side of your website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your `span` with `class="Ad-label"` inside the advertisement row like this:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row-sm-height">
            <span class="Ad-label">Advertisement</span>
                <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                <!-- Responsive Banner Ad -->
                <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                     style="display: block"
                     data-ad-client="ca-pub-2315506723267173"
                     data-ad-slot="5172135644"
                     data-ad-format="auto">
                </ins>
                <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And than apply this style:

```
.Ad-label
{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: @E. Agolli, this is great if the advertisement text is ontop, any ideas how to get it to appear to the left or the right of the image vertically?.

Comment: For this i think you should make the span of label and the script display inline-block and than apply this class to the label 
.vertical-text {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 transform-origin: left top 0;
        float: left;
}

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, the label should be a heading inside the section in order to identify the section as an advertisement [(read this)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section).

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <section>
    <h1 class="Ad-label">Advertisement</h1>
```

That being said, if you are trying to place the label on the right edge of the ad then change these two lines

```
position: absolute;
left: 13%;
```

to

```
position: relative;
left: 100%;
```

Comment: Hi @Arleigh Hix, I tried this and it looks like the advertisement is overlapping the label. http://snag.gy/EtFes.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution. Now the label is responsive with any size of advertisement. You can check using this if your issue will resolve. I have moved the label inside section for better and semantic code.
As your ad is not visible now, I have added custom height through CSS. Please remove the same while using this code with actual ad.
Check this https://jsfiddle.net/b2jL5z5w/ for preview.

```
<div class="ad-box">
    <section>
        <div class="Ad-label">Advertisement</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row-sm-height">
                <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                <!-- Responsive Banner Ad -->
                <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                     style="display: block"
                     data-ad-client="ca-pub-2315506723267173"
                     data-ad-slot="5172135644"
                     data-ad-format="auto">
                </ins>
                <script>
                    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

.ad-box{
    position:relative;
    background:#ccc; /*-please remove this while final output.-*/
}
.Ad-label {
    color: #444;
    background: #ddd;
    font-family: arial;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    margin:0;
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: left top;
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform-origin: left top;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    position: absolute;
    right: -86px;
    top: 0;
}

/*-this is temporary for height. please remove this while final output.-*/
.row-sm-height{
    height:150px; 
}
/*--*/
```